# SPListItem Indexer reports "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have the following code:

```
  try
  {
    string customerName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser != null ? 
        SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name.ToString() : "Customer";

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
      try
      {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(this.DesignJobListUrl))
        {
          using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
          {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPList list = web.GetList(this.DesignJobListUrl);
            SPListItem newListItem = list.Items.Add();

            newListItem["Customer Name"] = customerName;
            newListItem["Design Id"] = this.DesignStartResponse.DesignJobId;
            newListItem["Email"] = email;


            newListItem.Update();
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        innerEx = ex;
      }
    });
```

The problem is that the line `newListItem["Customer Name"] = customerName;`
throws a `Value does not fall within the expected range.` exception and I have no idea why. The other two assignments work fine.

The error is in the context of a .NET web application.

Comment: Step through it and see what the value of customerName at the critical juncture.

Comment: Is this for *SharePoint*?  I recall that vague error message driving me nuts when I was working with it.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon the value is a valid 11 characters string

Comment: Presumably SPListItem implements a custom indexer that is applying a value check and throwing that exception.

Comment: What type of columns is "Customer Name" , if its a people picker you cannot assign a string value to it and if memory serves you will see errors similar to the one you describe.

Comment: @Arcan.NET Well, actually this submits some things to the timer job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50357/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-but-the-field-exist

Try this:

```
newListItem.Properties["Customer Name"] = customerName;
```

Comment: Did this and the exception does not occur anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in designer that the list fields are named exactly like that:
"Customer Name", "Design Id", "Email".
Any extra/missing space, letter casing difference could cause the code not to work.